# How to reliably move functions from the Main method to another class

Tags: c#, methods

i am a C# beginner, so for now most of my code is inside the Main() method. I want to make my Program more object oriented so I want to move code from Main method to another class reliably(so i can do it with other programs as well).

```cs
    static void Main()
{
        int xLentgh = 20;
        int yLength = 20;
        
        Map.MapBuilder(xLentgh,yLength);
        int oldPositionX = 0;
        int oldPositionY = 0;
        int newPositionX = 0;
        int newPositionY = 0;
        if (oldPositionX == 0)
        {
            Map.WriteAt(".",newPositionX, newPositionY);
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo KeyStroke;
            KeyStroke = Console.ReadKey();
            
            switch (KeyStroke.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                {
                    if (newPositionX < xLentgh-1)
                    {
                        oldPositionX = newPositionX;
                        oldPositionY = newPositionY;
                        newPositionX++;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                {
                    if (newPositionX > 0)
                    {
                        oldPositionX = newPositionX;
                        oldPositionY = newPositionY;
                        newPositionX--;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                {
                    if (newPositionY > 0)
                    {
                        oldPositionX = newPositionX;
                        oldPositionY = newPositionY;
                        newPositionY--;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                {
                    if (newPositionY < yLength-1)
                    {
                        oldPositionX = newPositionX;
                        oldPositionY = newPositionY;
                        newPositionY++;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                default: break;
                
        }            
        
        Map.WriteAt(".",newPositionX, newPositionY);
        Map.WriteAt(" ",oldPositionX, oldPositionY);
}
}
```

In this code I create a "map" and using the switch statement in the for loop to "track" the position of the cursor. How do I write this code in a new class? I dont know where to start

Comment: It's unclear what parts you want to be in your class.  Just the tracking of the current position?  The map size?  The map itself?  Everything?  Should the class have the for loop in it and get input from the user?...or would that be outside of the loop and you simply tell the class to move up, down, left or right?  Some major design decisions need to be made here, and we can't make those for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create a [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/classes) named as you want (we will call it `RandomNameClass`) by declaring it outside of the bloc `class Program {}`.
You should have something like this :

```cs
namespace NameYouGaveToProject
{
    class RandomNameClass
    {

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Your actual code here
        }
    }
}
```

Above or under is fine but prefer having the class `Program` at the bottom if you write all your code in one file.

There you have your first custom class! Now try to add some [functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) in it. If you haven't learn about [instantiating a class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer) yet, just don't forget to add `public static` before the returning type of your function.

Example of what you could have :

```cs
namespace NameYouGaveToProject
{
    class RandomNameClass
    {
        // Function that doesn't return anything, returns "void"
        public static void SayHi()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi!");
        }

        // Function that returns a string
        public static string ReturnHi()
        {
            return "Hi!";
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Your actual code here
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can call them by typing the name of the class, followed by a point and then the name of the function and "()" if there are no [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters) to this function (there aren't in my example).

The syntax would be :

```cs
// Call the void function
RandomNameClass.SayHi();

// Call the function returning a string
string testVariable = RandomNameClass.ReturnHi();
```

Note that you can call as often as you want every function

And voilà! You know the basics of creating a class and call functions from this class! Next thing you should learn is how to make functions properly, and then instantiating a class and manage it's content

Comment: Thanks! That helped